# JSoup java login to webpage and query

Tags: java, parsing, authentication, jsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to build a java application where using JSoup library, I will login to an webpage(as it requires login), then do some queries using JSoup.

Below is the Login Page data:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0029)http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/ -->
<html lang="en-US"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="UDlORF9HSGMGfyJ1OBd/BgFjNCAKDDokYEgmDCY9cC09QSohLQURIg==">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="./Login_files/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./Login_files/site.css" rel="stylesheet">    <style>
    #popupbody {
     padding-top:0px;
     margin-top:0px;
     border-top-width:0px;

    }
    #popuphead {
     padding-top:0px;
     margin-top:-60px;
     border-top-width:0px;

    }

    #btnsubmit {
     margin-top:5px;
     padding-left:25px;
     padding-right:25px;
     margin-left:-25px;
     

    }
    #btnsubmit3 {
     margin-top:15px;
     padding-left:25px;
     padding-right:25px;
     margin-left:-25px;
     

    }
    </style>
    <link src="/ngn/vendor/kartik-v/dependent-dropdown/css/dependent-dropdown.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Login_files/dependent-dropdown.min.js.download" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrap">
        <nav id="w0" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"><div class="container"><div class="navbar-header"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w0-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php"> RC-</a></div><div id="w0-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse"></div></div></nav>
        <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="site-login">
    <h3>Login</h3>

    <p>Please fill out the following fields to login:</p>

    <form id="login-form" action="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/" method="post" role="form">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="UDlORF9HSGMGfyJ1OBd/BgFjNCAKDDokYEgmDCY9cC09QSohLQURIg==">
    <div class="form-group field-loginform-username required">
<label class="control-label" for="loginform-username">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="loginform-username" class="form-control" name="LoginForm[username]">

<p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
</div>
    <div class="form-group field-loginform-password required">
<label class="control-label" for="loginform-password">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="loginform-password" class="form-control" name="LoginForm[password]">

<p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
</div>
    <div class="form-group field-loginform-rememberme">
<div class="checkbox">
<label for="loginform-rememberme">
<input type="hidden" name="LoginForm[rememberMe]" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="loginform-rememberme" name="LoginForm[rememberMe]" value="1">
Remember Me
</label>
<p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>

</div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11" align="right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="login-button">Login</button>        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
</div>
</div>  <!--End Col 4 -->
</div> <!--End Row -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="pull-left">© RC 2021</p>
            <p class="pull-right">Developed by IT Team RC</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

<script src="./Login_files/jquery.js.download"></script>
<script src="./Login_files/yii.js.download"></script>
<script src="./Login_files/yii.validation.js.download"></script>
<script src="./Login_files/yii.activeForm.js.download"></script>
<script src="./Login_files/main.js.download"></script>
<script src="./Login_files/bootstrap.js.download"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('#login-form').yiiActiveForm([{"id":"loginform-username","name":"username","container":".field-loginform-username","input":"#loginform-username","error":".help-block.help-block-error","validate":function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {yii.validation.required(value, messages, {"message":"Username cannot be blank."});}},{"id":"loginform-password","name":"password","container":".field-loginform-password","input":"#loginform-password","error":".help-block.help-block-error","validate":function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {yii.validation.required(value, messages, {"message":"Password cannot be blank."});}},{"id":"loginform-rememberme","name":"rememberMe","container":".field-loginform-rememberme","input":"#loginform-rememberme","error":".help-block.help-block-error","validate":function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {yii.validation.boolean(value, messages, {"trueValue":"1","falseValue":"0","message":"Remember Me must be either \"1\" or \"0\".","skipOnEmpty":1});}}], []);
});</script>

</body></html>
```

AND BELOW is the QUERY page data:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0059)http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fquerynumber -->
<html lang="en-US"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="aVNEcTZGWWs/FShAURZuDjgJPhVjDSssWSIsOU88YSUEKyAURAQAKg==">
    <title>Number Query</title>
    <link href="./Number Query_files/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./Number Query_files/site.css" rel="stylesheet">    <style>
    #popupbody {
     padding-top:0px;
     margin-top:0px;
     border-top-width:0px;

    }
    #popuphead {
     padding-top:0px;
     margin-top:-60px;
     border-top-width:0px;

    }

    #btnsubmit {
     margin-top:5px;
     padding-left:25px;
     padding-right:25px;
     margin-left:-25px;
     

    }
    #btnsubmit3 {
     margin-top:15px;
     padding-left:25px;
     padding-right:25px;
     margin-left:-25px;
     

    }
    </style>
    <link src="/ngn/vendor/kartik-v/dependent-dropdown/css/dependent-dropdown.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Number Query_files/dependent-dropdown.min.js.download" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrap">
        <nav id="w1" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"><div class="container"><div class="navbar-header"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w1-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php"> RC-</a></div><div id="w1-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul id="w2" class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav"><li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Findex">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fquerynumber#" data-toggle="dropdown">User Role <b class="caret"></b></a><ul id="w3" class="dropdown-menu">
<
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="dropdown-header">Current User</li>
<</ul></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fquerynumber#" data-toggle="dropdown">FMT <b class="caret"></b></a><ul id="w4" class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=lfmt%2Findex" tabindex="-1">Lfmt Server Data</a></li>

</ul></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fquerynumber#" data-toggle="dropdown">View <b class="caret"></b></a><ul id="w5" class="dropdown-menu"><li class="active"><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fquerynumber" tabindex="-1">Number</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fquerycentrex" tabindex="-1">Centrex</a></li>

<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="dropdown-header">LMG</li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fqueryport" tabindex="-1">LMG Port</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fqueryslot" tabindex="-1">LMG Slot</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Flineparam" tabindex="-1">Number Status(LMG) </a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Flineparamp" tabindex="-1">Port Status (LMG)</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Flmgfac" tabindex="-1">LMG Sup Params</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fadslstat" tabindex="-1">ADSL Status</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fadslmac" tabindex="-1">ADSL MAC </a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="dropdown-header">HSS</li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fquerydynum" tabindex="-1">Dynamic Data</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=lmg%2Findex" tabindex="-1">LMG DataBase</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Flmgnumlist" tabindex="-1">LMG Numbers</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Flmgnumlistspare" tabindex="-1">LMG Spare Port</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Flmgnumcnt" tabindex="-1">LMG Working count</a></li></ul></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fquerynumber#" data-toggle="dropdown">Modify <b class="caret"></b></a><ul id="w6" class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Flmgportchg" tabindex="-1">Port Change</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Flmgblkportchg" tabindex="-1">Bulk Port Change</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fmodclip" tabindex="-1">Modify CLIP</a></li></ul></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fquerynumber#" data-toggle="dropdown">Reset <b class="caret"></b></a><ul id="w7" class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fresetpass" tabindex="-1">Reset Dynamic Lock</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fresetport" tabindex="-1">Reset LMG Port(Voice)</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fresetadsl" tabindex="-1">ADSL Port Reset</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Factadsl" tabindex="-1">ADSL Port Activate</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fdactadsl" tabindex="-1">ADSL Port DeActivate</a></li></ul></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fquerynumber#" data-toggle="dropdown">Test <b class="caret"></b></a><ul id="w8" class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Flooplinetest" tabindex="-1">POTS Loop Line</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fcktlinetest" tabindex="-1">POTS Circuit Test</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fselttest" tabindex="-1">ADSL SELT Test</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fdelttest" tabindex="-1">ADSL DELT Test</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fadslqlnup" tabindex="-1">ADSL QLN Uplink</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fadslqlndl" tabindex="-1">ADSL QLN Downlink</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fadslsnrup" tabindex="-1">ADSL SNR Uplink</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fadslsnrdl" tabindex="-1">ADSL SNR Downlink</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fping" tabindex="-1">Ping from LMG </a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Ftrace" tabindex="-1">Trace from LMG </a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Flmgalarm" tabindex="-1">LMG Alarms </a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fpglist" tabindex="-1">LMG PG List </a></li></ul></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fabout">About</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fcontact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogout" data-method="post">Logout (ctdngnl2)</a></li></ul></div></div></nav>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="breadcrumb"><li><a href="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="active">Number Query</li>
</ul>            
<div id="popup" class="fade modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h4> Bar Condition</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div id="popupContent"></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="popup_pc" class="fade modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h4> ADSL Profile Change</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div id="popupContents"></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div><div class="site-querynumber">
   

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
                    </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">

    <form id="w0" action="http://10.191.104.24/ngn/web/index.php?r=site%2Fquerynumber" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="aVNEcTZGWWs/FShAURZuDjgJPhVjDSssWSIsOU88YSUEKyAURAQAKg==">
        <div class="form-group field-querynumber-number required">
<label class="control-label" for="querynumber-number">Number</label>
<input type="text" id="querynumber-number" class="form-control" name="Querynumber[number]">

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>  </form></div>
    <div class="col-md-1">

       <div class="form-group" align="right"><br>
            <button type="submit" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- row -->

</div><!-- site-querynumber -->
</div>


        </div>
    

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="pull-left">© RC 2021</p>
            <p class="pull-right">Developed by IT Team RC</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

<script src="./Number Query_files/jquery.js.download"></script>
<script src="./Number Query_files/bootstrap.js.download"></script>
<script src="./Number Query_files/yii.js.download"></script>
<script src="./Number Query_files/yii.validation.js.download"></script>
<script src="./Number Query_files/yii.activeForm.js.download"></script>
<script src="./Number Query_files/main.js.download"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('#popup').modal({"show":false});
jQuery('#popup_pc').modal({"show":false});
jQuery('#w0').yiiActiveForm([{"id":"querynumber-number","name":"number","container":".field-querynumber-number","input":"#querynumber-number","validate":function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {yii.validation.required(value, messages, {"message":"Number cannot be blank."});}}], []);
});</script>

</body></html>
```

Now how to do this with JSoup. Please someone help.

Answer (score 0):

For the login, you need both the id of the input for the username and the id of the input for the password. In this case, these are `loginform-username` and `loginform-password`. The form is submitted by a `post` method.

Now you can just login with Jsoup.

```
HashMap<String, String> queryParams = new HashMap<>();
queryParams.put("loginform-username", "USERNAME");
queryParams.put("loginform-password", "PASSWORD");

Response response = Jsoup.connect(ROUTE).data(queryParams).post();
```

The response is the website which you get when you normally login.

If your website uses cookies, then you have to save them and pass them for the next requests.

```
HashMap<String, String> cookies = response.cookies();
```

Comment: tried your process, but still giving the same error.